# Can't see any logs on CloudWatch for my triggered Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudwatch

I've connected my Cognito to a DynamoDB table, so the information will go directly to the table, and to do so i created a Lambda function that will be triggered by Cognito.
i gave all the necessary permissions and added Importing logging to my function.

1st issue - when i signing up to the Cognito(getting in through Hosted UI), i don't see any items on my DynamoDB table.

2nd issue - i want to see what's wrong, but i can't find the function on CloudWatch logs.

*for some reason - on my friends account everything working just fine, we have no idea why it's not working on my account. what seems to be the issue?

Lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def read_items_from_dynamodb(table_name):
    table_name = os.environ["DYNAMODB_TABLE"]
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    
    response = table.scan()
    return response['Items']

def upload_to_s3(bucket_name, file_name, data):
    response = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name, Body=json.dumps(data))
    return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    try:
        logger.debug('## ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES')
        logger.debug(os.environ['LOG_BUCKET'])
        logger.debug(os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE'])
        logger.debug(os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_GROUP_NAME'])
        logger.debug(os.environ['AWS_LAMBDA_LOG_STREAM_NAME'])
        logger.debug('## EVENT')
        logger.debug(event)


        items = []
        table_name = os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE']
        user_name = event['userName']
        trigger_source = event['triggerSource']
        user_attributes = event['request']['userAttributes']
        email = user_attributes.get('email', '')
        login_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
        status = 'success' if trigger_source == 'PostAuthentication_Authentication' else 'failed'


        logger.debug(f"Event: {event}")
        logger.debug(f"Read 2 {len(items)} items from DynamoDB")
        logger.debug(f"Putting item to table: {table_name}") 
        logger.debug(f"Item to be written: {items}")
        table_name = os.environ["DYNAMODB_TABLE"]
        table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
        print(table)
        
        table.put_item(
                    TableName=table_name,Item={
                'user_id': user_name,
                'email': email,
                'login_time': login_time,
                'status': status    
            }
        )
        
        bucket_name = os.environ['LOG_BUCKET']
        items = read_items_from_dynamodb(table_name)
        logger.debug(f"Read {len(items)} items")
        file_name = 'dynamodb_items.json'
        upload_to_s3(bucket_name, file_name, items)

        return event
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("Error processing event")
        raise e
```

IAM:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "api-lambda-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "",
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Principal" : {
            "Service" : "lambda.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name        = "lambda-policy"
  description = "IAM policy for a lambda"
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : [
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
            "ssm:PutParameter",
          "ssm:DeleteParameter",
          "ssm:GetParameterHistory",
          "ssm:GetParameter"
          ],
          "Resource" : "*"
        },
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : ["dynamodb:PutItem", "dynamodb:Scan"],
          "Resource" : "*"
        },
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Resource" : ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket", "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"]

        },
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:GetLogEvents",
            "logs:FilterLogEvents"
          ],
          "Resource" : "*"
        },
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Action" : "lambda:InvokeFunction",
          "Resource" : ["*"]
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy_attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.lambda_policy.id
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_dynamodb" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_cognito" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonCognitoPowerUser"
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "full_admin" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
}
```

Lmabda configuration:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cognito" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCognito"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.arn
  principal     = "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.arn
}



resource "aws_lambda_function" "myfunction" {
  filename         = data.archive_file.post_authentication.output_path  
  function_name    = "myfunction"
  role             = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "myfunction.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 300
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.post_authentication.output_base64sha256
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.lambda_policy_attach
  ]
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = aws_subnet.public_subnets[*].id
    security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.vpc_endpoints.id}"]
  }
    environment {
    variables = {
      DYNAMODB_TABLE = aws_dynamodb_table.my_table.name
      LOG_BUCKET = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id
      
  }

} 
}
```

Comment: Check your Cloudwatch metrics for the lambda function and make sure it's being invoked.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct subnets for the Lambda function?

Comment: Why are you deploying to a VPC? A Lambda function in a VPC will not have access to DynamoDB or CloudWatch Logs without either a route to a NAT Gateway, or VPC endpoints for all those services. If it is not connecting to any resources inside the VPC there is no reason to deploy it into a VPC.

Comment: i can't see the metrics in the Lambda - it's not even got invoked for some reason that i don't know... i'm positive about the use of the right subnets, i got the VPC endpoint connected to my Dynamo and to S3, and of course i made all the right rules on the SG.

Comment: data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "dynaamo" {
  service = "dynamodb"
}


resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "dynamodbVP" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.dynaamo.service_name
  route_table_ids = [aws_route_table.second_rt.id]
}


resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s33" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.main.id
  service_name = "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.s3" 
  route_table_ids = [aws_route_table.second_rt.id]
}


resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_endpoints" {
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

Answer (score 0):

OK so i finally found what went wrong - why my Lambda didn't invoked by Cognito, why i haven't seen any item on DynamoDB table, why no file created on S3 and why i haven't seen any logs on CloudWatch.

the trigger in the cognito was "`post_authentication`" , when actually what i needed to trigger the lambda function was "`post_confirmation`". so i changed the Lambda config in my cognito to:

```
  lambda_config {
    post_authentication = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.arn
    post_confirmation   = aws_lambda_function.myfunction.arn
  }
```

and on my lambda function itself - i changed the trigger_source from "`PreAuthentication_Authentication`" to "`PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp`"

so it looks like this now:

```
items = []
table_name = os.environ['DYNAMODB_TABLE']
user_name = event['userName']
trigger_source = event['triggerSource']
user_attributes = event['request']['userAttributes']
email = user_attributes.get('email', '')
login_time = datetime.now().isoformat()
status = 'success' if trigger_source == 'PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp' else 'failed'
```

so now it's working, i can see all my logs, i can see the user information from Cognito on DynamoDB table, and i can see the date on a file created on S3 :)